# Botones Siguiente y Anterior para navegar entre celdas con fondo de color amarillo

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Me gustaría pedir su ayuda para hacer dos botones de navegación, en botón "siguiente" y el botón "anterior", la cosa es esta: tengo este buscador

[image]

Y cada vez que el usuario le de Click al botón "Siguiente" el programa debe ir a la siguiente celda coloreada de amarillo y hacerla la celda activa (para que pueda ser modificada) y si le da de nuevo a "siguiente" debe ir a la siguiente celda pintada de amarillo y así sucesivamente, y para el botón "Anterior" pues sería que regrese a la ultima celda donde estuvo.
Hasta ahora se que la condición que debería usar para buscar las celdas coloreadas es

> `Dim Clr As Long
>
>   Dim rng As Range
>
>   Dim Cell As Range
>
>   Clr = vbYellow
>
>   Rng = Activesheet.Range("A3:P88") 
>   For Each Cell in Selection 
>   If Rng = rng.Interior.Color = Clr Then
>
>   Cell = Activecell.Select`
>
> Y luego no se que hacer para que se marque como la celda activa, y después de eso pase a la siguiente celda.

Comment: No creo que la condición que mencionas funcione como piensas. Mira el código que está en artículo [Finding Cells Filled with a Particular Color](https://excel.tips.net/T002396_Finding_Cells_Filled_with_a_Particular_Color.html) en particular por atención a `For Each rCell In Selection`

Comment: Es difícil leer tu código. En lugar de colocarlo entre líneas colócalo como bloque usando apropiadamente la sangría y saltos de línea. Además es mejor que pongas un [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén, es que luego del If no se como mas avanzar, no se como decirla la condición de si la celda que esta evaluando es de color amarillo la haga la celda activa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el grabador de macros

Ejemplo del resultado de usar el grabador para encontrar la siguiente celda amarilla

```
Sub Siguiente()
'
' Siguiente Macro
'

'
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
End Sub
```

Luego al código anterior le cambiamos el nombre del Sub y SearchDirection:=xlNext por SearchDirection:=xlPrevious

```
Sub Anterior()
'
' Anterior Macro
'

'
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
End Sub
```

Luego asigna cada macro al botón correspondiente de tu formulario siguiendo las instrucciones de [Asignar una macro a un botón Formulario o Control](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/asignar-una-macro-a-un-bot%C3%B3n-formulario-o-control-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES)

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, estos códigos que me has dado funcionan muy bien, los seguiré estudiando junto con todas las paginas que me has dado para seguir avanzando con mi aprendizaje, muchas gracias